# Using macro from pgfkeys/.store as node name in tikzset .style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

My first post, so apologies for any etiquette failures.  For reasons not worth going into I want to decouple the definition of a whole bunch of tikz nodes from their eventual placement.  I'm wanting to have a LaTeX macro define separate .styles for each node, defining their contents, names etc. (and other stuff but skipped in this MWE).  However, I'm having a problem getting the node naming to work.  The attached MWE appears to work at face value, but if I then uncomment the \draw command on the third line from the end I get

> ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known.

I tried replacing `name=\nodename` with a similar pgfkeys invocation construct to the one I used to get the "node contents" part working but then I got a TeX capacity exceeded.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.  Apologies if the answer is readily found elsewhere and I missed it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\nodename}{}
\pgfkeys{mine/.cd, name/.store in=\nodename}

\newcommand{\makenodetype}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{mine/.cd,#1}
  \tikzset{\nodename/.style={%
      name=\nodename,
      rectangle,
      draw,
      node contents={\pgfkeys{mine/.cd,#1}\nodename}}}}

\makenodetype{name=A}
\makenodetype{name=B}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [A];
\node at (1,0) [B];
% \draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight in-line code in your post using back-ticks.

Comment: its working for me without any error. @Nathaniel Livesey

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Does that including when you re-enable the \draw command on the third line from the end?

Comment: Not really I'm afraid.  Your solution returns to the typical tikz approach I know and love.  What I'm trying to do, which I grant may be perverse, is to hide as much stuff away in the [] arguments, including both the node name and its contents. The goal of ultimate having a single style invocation as in my example.  I want to be able to define a whole bunch of complex nodes in one part of the source code, then place and connect them in a different part of the code.  I'll want to do the placing/connecting several different times with different levels of detail hence this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `\nodename` is not expanded when the style is defined, so when `name=\nodename` is executed it just uses whatever value is in `\nodename` when the style is used. So there is never a shape named `A`, because when the `A` style is executed `\nodename` is defined as `B`.

By putting `\makenodetype{name=B}` in between the the `\node` commands the example works. But this is not a very convenient way of working and while it is possible to use `\expandafter`, or an extra helper macro or two, it is worth nothing that the whole thing can be done with keys:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  my node/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    draw,
    name=#1,
    node contents=#1
  },
  declare my node/.style={
    #1/.style={my node=#1}
  }
}
\tikzset{
  declare my node=A,
  declare my node=B
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [A];
\node at (1,0) [B];
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, let me work with that (probably tomorrow at this point).  I forgot to mention, if I have a second (non pgfkeys-based) argument to my \makenodetype macro and use that (#2) to define the name it works (and your answer seems to take a similar approach from the quick look).  However (and I realize I didn't make this clear), I'm using pgfkeys here because in my non-MWE I plan to have many more arguments.

Comment: Mark, how does this work? Is the magic the use of `declare`? I see that there is a `/tikz/graphs/declare` in the manual but nothing else...

Comment: @Andrew the (arbitrarily named) key `declare my node` takes one argument (e.g., `A`) and simply creates a style key with the name of that argument (note that in `my node=#1` the `#1` is the argument to the outer `declare my node` key). When that style is called from the `\node` command, it executes the `my node` style key with the argument `A`, and `my node` then executes its options with `A` as its argument.